# best way to create a matrix with structs as its elements

Tags: c++

I have to create a force matrix for NxN elements, where every element is a force vector (fx,fy,fz). There are N particles and certainly `f[i][j]=f[j][i]` and  `f[i][i]= (0 0 0)` .

i tried:

```
 struct ftriple{
   double f[3];
 };

 std::vector<std::vector<ftriple>> Fmatrix(N, std::vector<ftriple>(N));
```

but i'm not satisfied with it, is there a better way to create a matrix with struct-elements?

(How can i use math-formula here?)

Comment: You tried "...". And?

Comment: Can you use 3rd party libraries? Eigen seems to be quite commonly used for this sort of thing.

Comment: I thought about Eigen but i was not sure, if i can use struct-elements in Eigen matrices. Is this possible?